# Testing Django Views with an ImageField

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have the following Model and Form

```
class AdImage(models.Model):
    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(Advertiser)
    picture = models.ImageField('Ad picture',
                            upload_to='ad_pics/%Y-%m-%d/')

class AdImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AdImage
        exclude = ['advertiser']

    helper = FormHelper()

    helper.layout = Layout(
        Div('picture'),
        FormActions(
            Submit('submit', "Sichern")
        )
    )
```

This is presented via :

```
class CreateAdImage(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    form_class = AdImageForm
    template_name = 'advertis/adimage_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug', None)
        advertiser = Advertiser.objects.get(slug=slug)
        form.instance.advertiser=advertiser

        form.save()

        ret = render(self.request, 'modal_form_success.html',
                 {
                     'success_message': "Bild gespeicher fuer %s gespeichert" %
                                        (advertiser.user.get_full_name()),
                     'reload' : True,
                 })

        return ret
```

This works pretty well. I can Test the Form with

```
class AdImageFormTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.creator = ShrUser.objects.create_user(username="foo", 
                         email="hallo.ich@localhost.de", password="bla")
        self.advertiser = Advertiser.objects.create(user=self.creator, 
                             city='Chicago')

        self.uploaded_image = get_temporary_image()

        self.form_data = {}
        self.file_dict = {
            'picture': self.uploaded_image,
        }

    def test_AdImageCreate(self):

        form = AdImageForm(self.form_data, self.file_dict)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Where self.uploaded_image is

```
def get_temporary_image():
    io = BytesIO()
    size = (200,200)
    color = (255,0,0,0)
    image = Image.new("RGBA", size, color)
    image.save(io, format='JPEG')
    image_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(io, None, 'foo.jpg', 'jpeg', 
                     image.size, None)
    image_file.seek(0)
    return image_file
```

But I cant get the view Test to run. I allways run into field required with :

```
    def test_create_adimage(self):

        advertiser = Advertiser.objects.create(user=self.user)

        response = self.client.get(reverse('create_adimage', kwargs={'slug' : advertiser.slug,}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'advertis/adimage_form.html')

        self.uploaded_image = get_temporary_image()

        post_data = {
        }

        file_dict = {
            'picture': self.uploaded_image,
        }

        response = self.client.post(reverse('create_adimage', kwargs={'slug': advertiser.slug,}),
                                post_data=post_data, file_dict=file_dict)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Does anybode know how to set post_data and file_dict in order to have a valid form ?

Kind regards

Michael

Comment: `client.post` should use the keyword argument `data=file_dict`.

Comment: Perfect. See Post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to AKS comment the following works perfect

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('create_adimage', kwargs={'slug': advertiser.slug,}),
                                post_data=post_data, data=file_dict)

self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
self.assertContains(response, 'Bild fuer %s gespeichert' % (advertiser.user.get_full_name()))
```

Comment: You don't need `post_data=post_data`.